# How to save, load and delete from database using a single ExtJS model?

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, extjs, model

Using ExtJS 6 one can have a store bind to the model and use the methods `sync` to save or `load` to load data.

I imagine that if a data is removed from store, upon calling `sync` the data will be removed from database too.

In my use case, I have different URLs and **mandatory** Ajax query fields for each action of create/update, load and delete data.

I have only seen examples showing load or save to storage, how can I declare the load, save and delete using Ajax in the same model?

Another doubt I have is that stores themselves can have a proxy, so they can perform those operations too, at least the load operation that I have seen in use. What's the difference between having these on the model or store? What's the best practice?

Example model from Sencha docs (is this only for read?):

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Base', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    }],

    schema: {
        namespace: 'MyApp.model',  // generate auto entityName

        proxy: {     // Ext.util.ObjectTemplate
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '{entityName}.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: '{entityName:lowercase}'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Another example I found on https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/classic/writer/writer.html using the `proxy` config, this seems more like what I would need as it specifies a URL for each operation:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Writer.Person',
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            api: {
                read: 'app.php/users/view',
                create: 'app.php/users/create',
                update: 'app.php/users/update',
                destroy: 'app.php/users/destroy'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                successProperty: 'success',
                root: 'data',
                messageProperty: 'message'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                writeAllFields: false,
                root: 'data'
            },
            listeners: {
                exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
                    Ext.MessageBox.show({
                        title: 'REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                        msg: operation.getError(),
                        icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        listeners: {
            write: function(proxy, operation){
                if (operation.action == 'destroy') {
                    main.child('#form').setActiveRecord(null);
                }
                Ext.example.msg(operation.action, operation.getResultSet().message);
            }
        }
    });
```

I believe I can have something like this in my case (this is just an example not tested!):

```
Ext.define('My.Person.Model', {
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            api: {
                read: 'http://myapiserver/getuser',
                create: 'http://myapiserver/upsertuser',
                update: 'http://myapiserver/upsertuser',
                destroy: 'http://myapiserver/removeuser'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                successProperty: 'success',
                root: 'data',
                messageProperty: 'message'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                writeAllFields: false,
                root: 'data'
            },
            // How can I have the parameters for each one?
            extraParams : {
              isuserUnderage : ' '
            , query          : '%'
         }
        }
    });
```

I have no idea how to do this, specially specifying parameters for each type of Ajax request (read, create, update, destroy), I can have an upsert request that will send all fields, but the remove request will require only the ID, the get request can have optional fields for filtering, like filtering persons by name.

---

Example to be more clear of the problem.

**Example data:**

```
[
  {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Fred",
      "age": 21,
      "sex": "m"
  },
  {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Susan",
      "age": 12,
      "sex": "f"
  },
  {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Marcus",
      "age": 22,
      "sex": "m"
  },
  {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Alex",
      "age": 32,
      "sex": "m"
  }
]
```

**Endpoints example:**

Endpoints have parameters, **these are mandatory**, this means that calling an enpoint without a parameter will cause a server error, also passing a parameter that is not specified will cause a server error! If a parameter is not necessary one can pass a string with a single whitespace  .

**To read:**

*Endpoint:* `http://myapiserver/getuser?query={query}`

Name is a filter by name, for example `http://myapiserver/getuser?query=fred` will bring users with name that has the string `fred`.

**To write, we usually have an upsert, so it works for both insert and update:**

*Endpoint:* `http://myapiserver/upsertuser?id={id}&name={name}&age={age}&sex={sex}`

So to update we can pass the ID: `http://myapiserver/upsertuser?id=1&name=Frederick&age=21&sex=m` and to insert we pass an empty string for ID: `http://myapiserver/upsertuser?id=  &name=Maurice&age=41&sex=m`

**To remove:**

*Endpoint:* `http://myapiserver/removeuser?id={id}`

Example: `http://myapiserver/removeuser?id=1`, removes person with ID 1.

Comment: It's a little difficult from your description to determine what you truly want... particularly `In my use case, I have different URLs and Ajax query fields for each action of create/update, load and delete data.`  How different are the URLs?  Do you have any starter code that you've tried?  The example you gave from Sencha docs isn't particularly useful.

Comment: Hi @incutonez I updated the question with more details. The thing is that I really don't know how to make this and what's the proper way to do it specially dealing with the different Ajax parameters. Also I don't know if I should do this on the `Model` or on the `Store` or have part of the Ajax configuration on one or another.

Comment: Howdy.  So you want a grid that loads each record individually for the GET URL and sends different params for each one, and the same for the other `actionMethods`?

Comment: @user5507535 you can do this either on the store or on the model. i would suggest to configure this on the store / proxy level. Configure the store with a rest proxy and call save on the model.

Comment: @incutonez I updated the question again with more details. What I need is to be able to specify the query parameters for each one of `read`, `create`, `update` and `destroy`. I have only seen one specifying the `extraParams` for all of them at once, which in my case doesn't work because if I provide one parameter more or a missing parameter I will have a server error in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Because you say it's mandatory to use `GET`s with query params, I would encourage you to rethink your tech stack because the RESTful verbs really make it more clear what your action is, and you remove the actual action from your URL routes.  However, I know sometimes this is totally out of our control, so I'll try my best here... I have to say, I've never experienced something like this, so I don't know if what I'm showing here is a best practice.

I can't show a true implementation because Sencha Fiddle is a simple sandbox, not meant for actual server-side implementations.  I'm also assuming that you're using the `classic` toolkit, but if you need it in `modern`, it's a fairly easy port that you can do.

I prefer the proxy inside of the model for several reasons... if I need to use this model in several different stores throughout my app, then each store will inherit the same proxy.  If I want to use the same model, but I don't want its proxy, I can simply override it when defining the store.  Also, if the proxy doesn't exist on the model, then the framework assumes what your URL should be, which doesn't work when I want to use models individually.

I think I've come up with what you're asking for in [this Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cof).  Really the core of what you want is in `GETUser.js`.

```
// We need to create our own proxy that will handle this for us
Ext.define('AjaxGet', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    alias: 'proxy.ajaxGet',

    // Per your requirement, we want to send individual requests
    batchActions: false,

    createOperation: function (action, config) {
        // This means we're doing an action against one of our records
        if (config && config.records) {
            if (action === 'destroy') {
                config.params = config.records[0].getDeleteParams();
            } else if (action === 'create' || action === 'update') {
                config.params = config.records[0].getUpsertParams();
            }
        }
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

// This is the desired, "GET" User model that uses GETs and query params for all actions
Ext.define('GETUser', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    idProperty: 'Id',
    fields: [{
        name: 'Name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'Id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'Age',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'Sex',
        type: 'string'
    }],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajaxGet',
        api: {
            read: 'Users',
            create: 'upsertuser',
            update: 'upsertuser',
            destroy: 'removeuser'
        },
        actionMethods: {
            create: 'GET',
            update: 'GET',
            destroy: 'GET'
        }
    },

    getUpsertParams: function () {
        const data = this.getData();
        // Means this record hasn't been saved, so we're in the CREATE state
        if (this.phantom) {
            // We don't want to send the ID with what the framework sets as the ID
            data.Id = undefined;
        }
        return data;
    },

    getDeleteParams: function () {
        return {
            Id: this.get('Id')
        };
    }
});
```

So what I ended up doing was creating a custom proxy that overrides the `createOperation` method to check which operation we're doing... based on that operation, we use the methods in the model to retrieve the params we want to send to the API.  You need `actionMethods` in the proxy because otherwise, they default to `POST`s.